# Let $ K=\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $V=K^{4}$. For subspace $W=lin((1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,1))\subset V$ find all subspace layers.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the task:

Let $ K=\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $V=K^{4}$. For subspace $W=lin((1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,1))\subset V$ find all subspace layers.

I know, that there is 16 vectors in $V$. My initial idea was to check all subspaces $\forall_{\alpha \in W} \ \ \ \alpha + W $, but there should be a clever way.

Please don't use advanced techniques, it's from first year algebra perparation book with tasks

Comment: $W$ has three nonzero vectors. So there are only $(16-1)/3=5$ layers. I think your idea is clever and neat enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonzero vectors in $W$ are  $(1,0,1,0)$, $(0,1,1,1)$, $(1,1,0,1)$. The solution takes about as long as writing it down:

- pick a nonzero vector not yet listed, such as $(1,0,0,0)$. Add it to nonzero vectors in $W$ to get $(0,0,1,0)$, $(1,1,1,1)$, $(0,1,0,1)$.
- pick a nonzero vector not yet listed, such as $(0,1,0,0)$. Add it to nonzero vectors in $W$ to get  $(1,1,1,0)$, $(0,0,1,1)$, $(1,0,0,1)$

and so on...